# Angularjs set value to ng-model

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to use ng-model to show a series of dropdowns. If I set the top select to empty option then the rest of the dropdowns should be set to the empty option.

```
<select ng-model="ddl">
<option></option>
<option>1</option>
<option>2</option>
<option>3</option>
</select>
<div ng-show="ddl">
<div ng-show="ddl != null">
    <select ng-model="ddl1">
        <option></option>
        <option>4</option>
        <option>5</option>
        <option>6</option>
    </select>
    <div ng-show="ddl1"> 
        <select>
            <option></option>
            <option>7</option>
            <option>8</option>
            <option>9</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

[JSFiddle-Link](http://jsfiddle.net/bs2x4q82/3/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the ng-change directive to run a funciton in your controller that set's the dropdowns to empty if the top one is empty.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChange#!

something like

```
$scope.reset = function() {
  if($scope.ddl === "") {
    $scope.ddl1 = ""; $scope.ddl2 = "";
  }
}
```